# Encode a string to Bytes 24bit with python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

I have an image code tostring in a pygame program :

```
img_string = pygame.image.tostring(img, "RGB")
```

I then save this string to a file and I want to be able to open it up again with the `image.tobuffer` function. However, I need to convert it back to 24bi bytes. I tried `img_bytes = bytes(img, 'utf-8')`, which of course doesn't work and I couldn't find how to get the format right.

Thanks very much if you can help me !

Answer (score 1):

Reasonably, and according to [the documentation](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/image.html), when you created it with `tostring()`, you should convert it back with `fromstring()`, not `frombuffer()`.

Comment: thanks for the answer, unfortunately fromstring doesn't work either. I had read the docs and tried fromstring but it raises the same error as frombuffer : string length does not match resolution and size.